# visual source safe is not comparing properly, it is showing some dots

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

One of my file is showing dots while comparing and some special character which is unreadable.(visual source safe 6.0 build 9848)

following is the extract

### Orignal was

f            f
fg

### but it is showing

1 Change: ÿþf        To: ÿþf
  2    Ins: 
  3    Ins:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to suggest to skip using this visual source safe feature. and just do compare and merge manually using a third party application like winmerge. you will save yourself a lot of headache

http://winmerge.org/?lang=en